# Underwater pyramids off the Cinque Terre

Tags: italy, identify-this, water-sports, cinque-terre

Several years ago I was travelling around Italy and doing a bit of long distance cycling and swimming with a friend. One day we were swimming 2 or 3 miles along the coast of the Cinque Terre in Italy heading north from Riomaggiore, about 3-500m off the coast. The sea was sparking clean and underwater visibility seemed to be 1000m (probably not, but it was amazingly clear).

During the swim we both stopped after observing a series of underwater pyramids. It was honestly the most unexpected thing I've ever seen. The sea bed seemed to be some 20-30m below and was completely sandy without any growth. On it were a series of pyramids perhaps 3-5, but this is something like 8 years ago now. The sides of the pyramids had cut-outs so you could see through, but it was too far down to investigate.

After almost expecting lights to start flashing and then the sea bed to rise up into the sky, nothing happened and we continued our swim. After returning to the hotel I immediately went online to try and find out what these things were. Nothing. I was possibly thinking they might be there to encourage coral growth. Every so often when I remember the experience, I go online and do a search, but still haven't found anything.

From memory I draw a poor (un)artist's impression of what it looked like. Has anyone got any idea?

[image]

Just in case anyone thinks I'm making this up, I swear this is genuine.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't remember. I've been there at least 3 times and remember camping one time, but don't remember about the others. Hotels and bed and breakfasts fade into a fuzzy memory for me. I remember ships and camping and things I don't do very often.

Comment: I'm not sure it would help, where I stayed, really. I can point to the exact place in the sea where the pyramids are if that helps?

Comment: I'm wondering, **at the time this happened,** when you went back to the hotel, did you immediately ask at the hotel about it?  So, you asked the staff, the manager, the waiters, the other guests ... *"Hey, what are those pyramid things!?"* - know what I mean?  Did you ask about it at the time, on the day?

Comment: No I didn't. I found it incomprensible that there could be some massive underwater ecological protrection programme or scientific experiment on such a scale that it wasn't on the internet.

Comment: You were swimming with the one friend (A), in fact were you on holidays with only the one friend, A?  Or when you got back to the hotel, were you part of a bigger group?  If so, did you and A at that time tell the others about the incident?  Secondly what in fact is A's opinion of an explanation??

Comment: I was just swimming with the one friend. We both observed the pyramids, there was nobody else. A has no idea either! There has to be a logical explanation that is's for coral generation or something! Nobody else would have swum out such as distance, so unless they were on a boat and went snorkelling, it wouldn't have been seen.

Comment: http://www.basspro.com/Offshore-Angler-16-Star-Crab-Trap/product/10216037/

Comment: @ceejayoz absolutely no way! These things were at least 5m high made of what looked like concrete. Not unless they were killer whale traps!

Comment: just FTR. that type of crab trap lays **flat** (opened out) on the sea floor.  the only time it assumes that shape is simply when you pull it up.

Comment: Also worth noting that Cinque Terre is a national park and any fishing activity would be fairly illegal. But are you able to point to the precise location on maps? That might be useful.

Comment: Yeah, let's have a map with an X on it ...... that can't be hard to figure!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is only a guess of course but based on the circumstances you describe and your drawing, these might be [artificial reefs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_reef) ([barriera artificiale in Italian](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barriera_artificiale)).

These can come in [a variety of forms](https://www.google.it/search?q=artificial%20reef&biw=1643&bih=907&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLr6myr5TNAhWFHxoKHeYzBkUQ_AUIBigB) including ships, tanks, cars, train cars and simple concrete structures. [Here is a google images result of structures that are fairly similar to the one you have drawn](https://www.google.it/search?tbm=isch&tbs=rimg%3ACZAoPRsPBRQjIjgYwiaWQVRMQBh5pC05_1MjAWsNMvnQSKipFib36h4aBea6h4Vwi72bVxpaYvrNoPp4lMb1Yf-PV3ioSCRjCJpZBVExAEf6GMQPFizCQKhIJGHmkLTn8yMAR0KFw65bahFkqEglaw0y-dBIqKhElKU386B2HASoSCUWJvfqHhoF5EfbFkCwoJU75KhIJrqHhXCLvZtUR89aELTGJA7UqEgnGlpi-s2g-nhHgCLR2MbteByoSCSUxvVh_149XeEcJq03rVAnUx&q&bih=907&biw=1643&ved=0ahUKEwi5ht_9rJTNAhXJPBQKHUGeBkUQ9C8ICQ&dpr=1). Some of these pics have humans next to them and from my guesses these structures are 1-6 meters tall.

Artificial reefs can have tons of different purposes (block ships from passing, prevent erosion, ...) but my best guess here is to serve as a habitat for marine life, given that [Cinque Terre is a marine protected area](http://www.parconazionale5terre.it/Earea-marina-protetta.php).

Further support for my theory comes from [this report (in Italian) from 2010](http://www.parconazionale5terre.it/dettaglio.php?id=9562) describing such measures of the beach of Corniglia (now I doubt you swam this far up, if so kudos) and similar structures might well be in place off Riomaggiore. It says the objects were submerged in a depth of 7-9 meters in sandy ground, to prevent erosion of the sandy beach and as a habitat for fish. They still leave 5-7 meters of water depth for ships/boats. They should also be marked in sea maps for boats but I can't find any such for the Cinque Terre right now.

Update: You specified having swum up all the way to Corniglia so it fits. [This link you found actually shows the artificial reef structures on land and how they were submerged](http://www.marittimasubservice.it/multigallery/detail/index/id/7/barriera-antierosione-corniglia-sp.html/) off the beach of Corniglia, while [this video shows them underwater](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJ5QOpRFses). From the pictures I guess 2-3 meters tall. Their purpose, given the report from 2010 might be more to prevent beach erosion than I thought, as there seems to be some strong seasonal currents taking away and filling up the sandy beach.
[Here](http://www.comune.avola.sr.gov.it/portale/allegati/vivereilmare/01%20Rel%20Tecnico%20Finale%20Avola%20%20ULTIMA%2012.09.14.pdf) is a detailed documentation (in Italian, pictures included) of a similar project in Sicily.
The artificial reefs seem to be of [this brand](http://www.tecnoreef.it/).

[image]

Image courtesy tecnoreef.it

Comment: Wow, those google images do look like strong contenders for what I saw.. Also I did read about erosion along the coast so this is looking like it might be it! Thanks! I'm going to do a bit more research.

Comment: We did swim up to Corniglia. Looking on google satellite maps I think that's where we got out.

Comment: http://www.marittimasubservice.it/multigallery/detail/index/id/7/barriera-antierosione-corniglia-sp.html/ - definitely the right answer. Thanks!

Comment: It would be great to include a picture in this answer but I have not found anything of a similar structure where a good license is clearly marked. If anyone does find it, please edit.

Comment: A spectacular find, mts !!!  Congrats.  An interesting point, @berwyn, is that those things would almost certainly still be in place (I guess now overgrown dramatically).  You could go back, swim again, and see the change.

Comment: @JoeBlow I intend to and take a photo. I'm certain they weren't 2m tall, but maybe my memory is playing tricks on me.

Comment: Right, I just mean, it will be cool to see all the coral/whatever that has developed on them.

Comment: I think [**this article in Italian**](http://www.parks.it/parco.nazionale.cinque.terre/dettaglio.php?id=9156) confirms most of the info in this answer